# from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qt-designer

I created a form with QT Designer, then converted it to a .py file. An error occurs with the line `import : from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas`. It's not recognized. How can I resolved this error in order to run the app ? I'm working on eclipse, on ubuntu. I don't see python in this folder /usr/share/qgis/python/

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(453, 323)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.widget = QgsMapCanvas(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shos Map"))

from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

1- I installed python-qgis : **sudo apt-get install python-qgis**
1- In Eclipse, i seted the interpreter to Python3 by adding this : **/usr/bin/python3**